# Facebook C# SDK v5.0 - How to run the sample application?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I've downloaded Facebook C# SDK v5.0 and I would appreciate some help to run the sample.

Isn't just "open website" by pointing to a folder under the samples folder

eg. CSASPNETFacebookApp

and run "start debugging" ?

I'm using Visual Web Developer 2010 Express.

Answer (score 1):

it should have sample folder navigate to it and select sample application but before you do that you should have an application registered at facebook developers which will give you the Application ID to use in samples or your code.with out it you cannot use the samples

Comment: i've registered for the application and got the application id and stuff. What do you mean by "navigate to it and select sample application"?

Comment: the facebook sdk you have downloaded contains the demo you needed so run and give it your app id and see the magic

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to make sure you've created an app at https://developers.facebook.com/apps. You need a developer account for this.

After creating and configuring your new app, you get an APP ID/KEY and APP SECRET. You need to put those inside the web.config file of the samples.

Second of all, those samples only run on IIS. So you need to have it installed and configured on your PC. You should be using VS2010 and .NET 4.0. IIS should be configured to use 4.0. You then create a new aplication inside IIS, point it to the folder where the sample you want to run is and then browse with http://localhost.

For example. I'm browsing a sample with http://localhost/CS_AspNetWebForms_JsSdk

IIS 7.5 was using .NET 2.0 as default on my PC. Also, enable directory browsing just to make browsing of the samples easier.
IIS should also have the correct Handler Mappings to run .aspx files.

Just downloading and debugging will not work.